# QGIS crashes when adding ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, feature-service, qgis-2.16

I want to add an ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer into QGIS. I can add the layer sucessfully but as its being downloaded if I ask QGIS to do anything else it crashes.

First I bring up the **Add ArcGisFeatureServer Layer from a Server** dialog box. I can connect to the server fine as you can see in the screenshot. The url for the resource is http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Survey_Mark/MapServer. Then I click **Add**.

[image]

At first the dataset appears to be downloading fine.

[image]

When I attempt to zoom in on an area it initially looks ok but shortly crashes.

[image]

If I choose the debug option I get the following exception.

[image]

Am I adding the web service incorrectly? I've tried ticking on the **Only request features overlapping the current view extent**. No difference. I've added the layer when I was at a zoom level where I knew there are only 3 points. I get the blue loading bar but no features turning up. I assume its downloading them all over the state and not at the extent I'm zoomed to. If I attempt to move around then the same crash occurs.

I'm running QGIS 2.16.3.

Comment: I believe this was fixed in a more recent build - possibly 2.18.10 or above.

Comment: Just tried to do the same process on 2.18.16. Same result. Same exception thrown.